# Getting error on real device using DLLImport in Xamarin.ios: "Attempting to JIT compile method 'mymethod(string,string)' while running in aot-only"

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Using latest Visual studio for Mac 8.0.9.
My stuff works on ios simulator perfectly, function is called, returning the valid result.

But its not working on a real device.  Device is a iPad 5th gen so arm64.
Using fat lib, lipo verified that arm64, x86, armv7 are all there.

The error i get: Attempting to JIT compile method 'mymethod (string, string)' while running in aot-only mode.

Using c# DllImport to call the function in the project directly:
[global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("__Internal", EntryPoint = "mymethod")]
public static extern global::System.IntPtr mymethod(string arg1, string arg2);

These are static built c libraries there is no any generic stuff in those.

I enabled the optimisation in the compiler, didnt help.

Thanks for any help!

Here is a sample with the c lib, swigger, xcode project to build the lib and the xamarin.ios project using the built lib with pinvoke.

https://gofile.io/?c=yIvExk

Comment: Have you tried turning off LLVM ?

Comment: Its turned off.

Comment: In the iOS project settings, when you go to "Compiler" and "iOS Build", when you switch from iPhone Simulator to iPhone, are all the settings the same?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same.
I tried this "Dont link" option as well, but did not work.
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/89104/about-aot-only-error-please-help

Comment: @Will1Am Did you define some generic types in your method? Can you post more code?

Comment: No generic at all in the entire invoke class and anywhere its called from.
 i am using int, IntPtr and string.

I tried it only using int, not even string, but same error.
Calling it like: INVOKE.mymethod("aaa", "bbb")

Comment: I added a sample with all the stuff i have